# How to show image and video as thumbnail in grid view?

Tags: java, android

I have a database which contains list of image and video path. My problem is I have to show all the images and video in a `GridView`. I have taken list of path from database but I am not able to show them in GridView. Please help me. Here is my code. 
Thanks in Advance

```
 public class GridGallery extends Activity
{

    ArrayList<String>list;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grid_gallery);
        DataModel dbModel = new DataModel(this);
        list = dbModel.selectAll();

        GridView sdcardImages = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.sdcard);
        sdcardImages.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    }


     /**
     * Adapter for our image files.
     */
    private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private final Context context; 

        public ImageAdapter(Context localContext) {
            context = localContext;
        }

        public int getCount() 
        {
            return list.size();
        }
        public Object getItem(int position) 
        {
            return position;
        }
        public long getItemId(int position) 
        {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            ImageView picturesView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                picturesView = new ImageView(context);

                for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
                {
                    Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(list.get(i));
                    picturesView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
                }
                picturesView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                picturesView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
                picturesView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
            }
            else 
            {
                picturesView = (ImageView)convertView;
            }
            return picturesView;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. Is there a reason why the images and videos are not showing up.  What **exactly** are you having difficulty with here?  Are you able to output anything to a log?  Please provide some code to help us help you

Comment: I am only getting the Three thumbnails of single file

Comment: print out your list in the log and see what it says

`for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
Log.e("LOGTAG LIST", list.get(i));
}`

Comment: @MutMatt:- I have removed the for loop and used:-                    Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(list.get(position));
So it is working fine for images but it is not showing video's thumbnails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes..

I got the answer after a long experiment: here it is:

```
public class GridGallery extends Activity
{
    ArrayList<String>list;    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grid_gallery);
        DataModel dbModel = new DataModel(this);
        list = dbModel.selectAll();

        GridView sdcardImages = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.sdcard);
        sdcardImages.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));    
    }    

     /**
     * Adapter for our image files.
     */
    private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private final Context context;     
        public ImageAdapter(Context localContext) {
            context = localContext;
        }

        public int getCount() 
        {
            return list.size();
        }
        public Object getItem(int position) 
        {
            return position;
        }
        public long getItemId(int position) 
        {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            ImageView picturesView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                picturesView = new ImageView(context);    
                 if(list.get(position).contains(".jpg"))
                {
                     bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(list.get(position)); //Creation of Thumbnail of image
                }
                else if(list.get(position).contains(".mp4"))
                {
                    bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(list.get(position), 0); //Creation of Thumbnail of video
                }
                picturesView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                picturesView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
                picturesView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
            }
            else 
            {
                picturesView = (ImageView)convertView;
            }
            return picturesView;
        }
    }

}
```

This works fine for me

Comment: How are you using ThumbnailUtils? I no longer see that import available... was android.media.ThumbnailUtils. Anyone know if this is still useable?

Comment: yes.. this is available and working fine for me... I sort out my issue by using this

Comment: I've realized this became available in api 8. I wasn't seeing this because I was using 7.

Comment: @balbanshah : do u have any idea how to capture frames from video?

Comment: @balbanshah is there any way to create the thumbnail of other documents like pdf,word,....

Answer (score 1):

You have to just add this line before your return of the picturesView

Just add this

```
picturesView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

just after this :

```
picturesView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
```

You will get it what you are willing to get!
Hope it'll help. I know I'm bit late but may be it'll be helpful someone else who is need of it.