# extract frames from a video file in android

Tags: android

I am trying to extract frames from a video file in android. I have searched alot but couldn't find any clue about that. Is there any way we could do this? Could anyone please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm late but,.

Use a library called - FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever

Add this line in your build.graddle under module app:

`compile 'com.github.wseemann:FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever:1.0.14'`

Rebuild your project.

Use the FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever class to extract frames,. follow the steps:

```
FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever med = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();


med.setDataSource("your data source");
```

and in your loop you can grab frame using:

```
 Bitmap bmp = med.getFrameAtTime(i*1000000,FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

`Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoFile, 0);`

and also please visit two sites
[How to show image and video as thumbnail in grid view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507482/how-to-show-image-and-video-as-thumbnail-in-grid-view)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/ExtractVideoFrames.aspx

Comment: hi balban... thanx alot for your reply... i see that the second link(java code) doesn't seem to be compatible for android. What all i need to do is get the RGB values of each frame from a video file. So for that i am trying to extract all the frames in the video.

Comment: thats Gr8... if you find answer useful please mark as correct. That Other can take advantage of this. Thanks