# Grab frame from video file in Android

Tags: java, android, video

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [extract frames from a video file in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869008/extract-frames-from-a-video-file-in-android)

I would like to get (extract) frames from a video file.

Apparently, it's not possible with Android API.

I see that it's possible to do that with FFmpeg, but I'm not able to compile FFmpeg an use it in an Android project.

Is there way to extract video frames in Android?

Comment: Have a look through these [search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+capture+video+frame)

Comment: Also check out this detailed post for [FFMPEG on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725773/ffmpeg-on-android)